# Awk: Var types and output format

Tags: variables, awk

This is my super complex awk program:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
count = 0
}

{ if ( $1 == "r" )
    {
    nom = $2 
    ip= $7
    numerolinea = NR
    }
 else { 
  where = match($0, "Fast")
  if ( where ) 
    {
     count++
     printf( "\t%5i %20s %15s\n",count,nom,ip )     
    }
      } 
}
```

So as you can see `nom` and `ip` are treated as strings each one with its own length. An excerpt of the output it'd be like this:

```
    | 111          cutemyserver1     93.27.255.24 |                                                                                       
    | 112 thisisthenamemyserver2     60.231.2.255 |                                                                                       
    | 113   anotherlongmyserver3   191.44.192.260 |                                                                                       
    | 114              myserver4   173.374.76.183 |                                                                                       
    | 115           formyserver5    145.146.321.8 |                                                                                       
    | 116              myserver6     64.31.359.70 |                                                                                       
    | 117        foofoomyserver7    245.16.19.338 |
```

As you also can see, `count` is an integer. My goal is `count`to be aligned as `nom` and `ip` do are, because of this:

```
    | 8            myserver6  91.580.144.231 |                                                                                         
    | 9                narnd   163.11.783.10 |                                                                                         
    | 10                erreer   59.194.0.353 |                                                                                        
    | 11                111111  178.70.644.91 |
```

But cheating wih `%5i` doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You can print `count` also using `%5s` or `%-5i`

Comment: Try using `%5d` instead of `%5i`

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed your problem and taken the liberty of making your code more "awk-like":

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

$1=="r" {nom=$2;ip=$7;next;}

/Fast/ {printf "\t%5d %20s %15s\n",++count,nom,ip;}
```

NB.

1. `count` doesn't require initialisation in this example.
2. `numerolinea` is unreferenced
3. `condition {...}` is a more "awk-like" way of saying `if...then`
4. `next` prevents the subsequent conditions being tested
5. `++count` updates the variable before offering its value
6. `/Fast/ {...}` executes when the regular-expression `Fast` is in `$0`
7. As Glenn correctly states, `%5d` is the syntax you require within your `printf`

Comment: @groovyspaceman: Thanks for your lesson. I didn't know about `next`<br>

Comment: So to the point: this awk is actually invoked from a bash script, so if I use `%5d` it works just in the case it is invoked in the -let me say- standalone awk way. But `%-5i` does the trick if invoked from the bash script.